# Laravel PayPal payment packages

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5

Is there any packages that I can use for `laravel 5.1` PayPal payment method? 
I have come across the git and resources, but so far found none that works for latest release.

The one that popular but outdated is [laravel-paypalpayment](https://github.com/xroot/laravel-paypalpayment).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I use PayPal's official php sdk [`paypal/rest-api-sdk-php`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) package to create my own service provider. PayPal has good documentation in its Github page. Try at first place the [introduction](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call#instructions) sample:

```
// After Step 1
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'AYSq3RDGsmBLJE-otTkBtM-jBRd1TCQwFf9RGfwddNXWz0uFU9ztymylOhRS',     // ClientID
        'EGnHDxD_qRPdaLdZz8iCr8N7_MzF-YHPTkjs6NKYQvQSBngp4PTTVWkPZRbL'      // ClientSecret
    )
);
```

Comment: paypal/rest-api-sdk-php package is deprecated. Package paypal/rest-api-sdk-php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[This one](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) works well with Laravel (composer in general) and works on the Classic API which is a lot more mature and has more features than the REST API.

Comment: The files has been downloaded, how can I create config file? And how about `providers` and `aliases`?

Comment: You may want to [review this project](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass) for details.  It's basically a [replica of PayPal.com](http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com/) that I did in Laravel using the PayPal library.  It's not complete, but is good for review.  As for the config file, there is a [paypal.php file in /app/config/](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass/blob/master/app/config/paypal.php).